# Version unspecified in dependencies of file pom

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, maven-plugin

I'm running into an error in my .pom files when building builds. I have separated the project into different daughter libraries but now when uploading a version to be able to use this library in other apps I have encountered a problem. In my generated .pom file I am finding dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>NameLibrary</groupId>
<artifactId>id</artifactId>
<version>unspecified</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The version number comes to me "unspecified". I have read some posts about how to modify the .pom file before it is uploaded to place a version but they are not working for me. It seems that the posts I have read are outdated since they are from a few years ago.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
```

...

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'XXXXXXX'
                artifactId = 'XXXXXXX'
                version = 'XXXXXXX'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the solutions are using pom.whenConfigured but that method does not appear to me, so I do not know if it is a problem with the version that I have or if it is another problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the version tag so the maven will pick the latest tag for the dependency

Comment: The version tag cannot be deleted as it is the .pom file that is auto-generated.